# Reindex sublevel in pandas multiindexed dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index, reindex

I'm trying to reindex a dataframe's multiindex at one sublevel. The df in question looks like this:

```
test = pd.DataFrame({
  'day':[1,3,5],
  'position':['A', 'B', 'A'],
  'value':[20, 45, 3] 
})
test.set_index(['day', 'position'])

>>                  value
  day   position
   1      A          20
   3      B          45
   5      A          3
```

And my goal is to reindex the `day` level to transform the dataframe into the following:

```
>>>
              value
day position    
 1    A       20.0
 2    A       20.0
 3    A       20.0
 4    A       20.0
 5    A       3.0
 1    B       0.0
 2    B       0.0
 3    B       45.0
 4    B       45.0
 5    B       45.0
```

So essentially I need to reindex `day` to days 1 through 5 for every position group and then forwardfill and fillna with 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

- first reshape by [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html)
- add mising days by [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html)
- forward fill by `ffill`
- replace first `NaN`s by [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html)
- reshape by by [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html)
- [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) for expected output

---

```
df = (test.set_index(['day', 'position'])
          .unstack()
          .reindex(range(1,6))
          .ffill()
          .fillna(0)
          .stack()
          .sort_index(level=[1,0]))
print (df)
              value
day position       
1   A          20.0
2   A          20.0
3   A          20.0
4   A          20.0
5   A           3.0
1   B           0.0
2   B           0.0
3   B          45.0
4   B          45.0
5   B          45.0
```

Comment: You beautiful genius creature. Thank you :)

Comment: @Nico - You get nice question, it is very important for answering ;)

Answer (score 1):

I reorder your index

```
test.set_index(['position', 'day']).reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['A','B'],list(range(1,6))])).sort_index().groupby(level=0).ffill().fillna(0)
Out[30]: 
     value
A 1   20.0
  2   20.0
  3   20.0
  4   20.0
  5    3.0
B 1    0.0
  2    0.0
  3   45.0
  4   45.0
  5   45.0
```